# Activity is null when try to take screen shot

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

My project type is PCL in xamarin Forms. I want to take screenshot and I am using below code. But when I debug my code `Activity` is always null. I am trying to figure out the issue but not get success. Can you please tell what i am doing the mistake.

```
public interface IScreenshotManager
{
   Task<byte[]> CaptureAsync();
}
```

For Android:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(ScreenshotService))]
namespace MyProject.Droid
{
    public class ScreenshotService : IScreenshotService
    {
        public static Activity Activity { get; set; }               

        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<byte[]> Capture()
        {
            if (Activity == null)  // Activity is always null Error here
            {
                throw new Exception("You have to set ScreenshotManager.Activity in your Android project");
            }

            var view = Activity.Window.DecorView;
            view.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;

            Bitmap bitmap = view.GetDrawingCache(true);

            byte[] bitmapData;

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
                bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
            }

            return bitmapData;
        }
    }

}
```

Calling the function

```
 byte[] screenshotData = await DependencyService.Get<IScreenshotService>().Capture();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously `Activity` is `null` if you don't assign it. You can use the `CurrentActivity` nuget package to get the current activity (or you may assign it in `Activity` `OnCreate` method as Xamarin uses always the same `Activity` from the start).

Comment: how can i assign activity onCreate

Comment: It should be ScreenshotService.Activity = this;

Answer (score 1):

The old deprecated way would be `var view = ((Activity)Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context).Window.DecorView;`
Xamarin automatically assigns the `Activity` to `Forms.Context`.Since the release of Xamarin 2.5, `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context` is obsolete.

Now you could use this :

```
var currentContext = Android.App.Application.Context;
```